# Shopify Liquid - Forlooping on Strings

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I have just started using shopify and have run into my first issue I have not been able to solve though the shopify docs or google searches. My goal to my mind a simple one but has given me much trouble. So here it is.

Using liquids schema I have created a variable `input` of type text(string) with a value of no importants. What is important is the ability to loop through the `input` variable so that i can look at each character in a dynamic manner.

#### Variations Tried:

```
{% for char in section.settings.input %} // Loop 1
    {{ char }} <-- char is never displayed -->
{% endfor %}

{% for input_idx in (0..section.settings.input.size) %} // Loop 2
    <div class="example 1">{{section.settings.input[input_idx]}}</div>
    <div class="example 2">{{section.settings.input[forloop.index]}}</div>
    <div class="example 3">{{section.settings.input | split: input_idx}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

### Conclusion

So far in every variation tried I can not isolate the characters of the string. Loop 2 allows me to loop the length of the string but not access individual parts of it.

If what I'm suggesting is not possible is there a way to split the string into and array dynamically.

I haven't posted in a long time so sorry if I've forgotten or made a mistake. Thanks for any help I'm stuck so any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the string and make it in array before looping it.

So you just need to do the following:

```
{% assign text_arr = section.settings.input | split: '' %}
```

Where `split: ''` will split every character. Then you loop the `text_arr` instead.

Comment: Oh, cool thats easy. I'm still not used to liquefy's syntax  i was assuming that split would only do so under a condition, by a null condition makes sense to split the full string.

Comment: I have applied the the assignment and changed to object used in the forloop ti the generated array and it works smoothly now. @drip thanks

Comment: @Crispy np. Good luck!